# Unable to print the contents of an ArrayList of ArrayLists to a file

Tags: java, file

I am trying to print the contents of an `ArrayList` which contains `ArrayList`s of integers to a CSV file. The code shows the method I use, which received a `PrintWriter`. Neither the commented out code nor the executable code work. After the program runs, I open the CSV file to find it is empty. I have tested to make sure the `ArrayList` has contents in it by printing to the console. It does. Not sure what's going wrong here!

```
static void printCountTrackerFile(PrintWriter out_2) { 

//      for(int i =0; i <bustByCount.size(); i++) { 
//          out_2.print(bustByCount.get(i) + "\n");
//      }

    for (ArrayList<Integer> each : bustByCount) { 
        for(Integer r : each) { 
            out_2.print(r + ",");
        } 

        out_2.print("last" + "\n"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: try wrapping it in a try catch so you can get some error messages. also could be a file permission issue depending on your os so check that. do both of those loops print the values correctly? looks like the commented one prints by row and the other one prints by column

Comment: How does this method get called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to call `out_2.flush();` so it clears the buffer and writes to the file.

Answer (score -1):

*for* `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> bustByCount` *the lambda expression would be:*

```
bustByCount.stream().forEach(
  a -> {
    a.forEach( i -> out_2.print( i + ", " ) );
    out_2.println( "last" );
  } );
```

*because of the lack of clarity:*
– works because `PrintWriter::println` does an internal flush
– avoids the stylistic ugliness `"last" + "\n"` in `out_2.print("last" + "\n")` that unnecessarily creates an extra string object
– is more readable (not least because of the shortness)

Comment: But how is this any improvement or an answer to the question?

Comment: This one works without any flush()-ing what I think is an improvement. And by the way it's shorter.

Comment: Shortness is not a virtue in itself. If if works without flushing, that would be due to the use of `println()` instead of `print()` and nothing to do with lambda stuff.